# Will Microsoft continue to improve WebGL support in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, webgl

Current support for asm.js based WebGL apps (such as apps exported from Unity5) run extremely slowly on IE11. Is this feature still in active development?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is extremely unlikely that Microsoft will now continue to add or significantly improve any features in IE11, because all their development effort is going into the Edge browser.

With Edge being released this month alongside Windows 10, IE11 should now be considered a legacy browser.

The flip side is that the kind of improvements you're looking for are extremely likely to appear in Edge, and since Edge is now intended to be continually updated, once it becomes established, you should see users getting new features and improvements much more quickly than has traditionally been the case with IE.

Comment: Agree that most of the effort will now go into the Edge browser. The wild card is that Edge will only run on Windows 10 and forward so there will likely be a large base using IE11 for a while.

Comment: This is illustrated by the [platform status page](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/?filter=f3e0000bf&search=webgl), especially when you filter it down to WebGL.